# VHDL - Design Library Does Not Contain Unit

Tags: vhdl

I have the following architecture:

```
architecture datapath of DE2_TOP is
begin
U1: entity work.lab1 port map (
    clock => clock_50,
    key => key,
    hex6 => hex6,
    hex5 => hex5,
    hex4 => hex4
);
end datapath;
```

I am getting the following error: `Error (10481): VHDL Use Clause error at DE2_TOP.vhd(276): design library "work" does not contain primary unit "lab1"` on the line: `U1: entity work.lab1 port map (`. Anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: Could you show what VHDL source code you have for the `lab1(.vhd)` entity? (If any?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have compiled at least the `entity`for `lab1` before you compile `DE2_TOP`

Comment: ... unless you instantiate lab1 as a Component rather than as an Entity.